# Ways to hide an IP?

Tags: networking

I was reading ["HOW TO surf anonymous"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=95527), following which I typed

```
$ sudo apt-get install tor privoxy
```

But it seems like the package is not available

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate
```

So I was wondering what are some good and convenient ways to hide ip?

Is it by using proxy? If yes, does it provide a list of proxies to save me from looking up by Google, and do I have a choice for where the new ip will be from?

My main browser is Firefox 3.6.17 and sometimes I am using Google Chrome. My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.

Thanks!

Comment: Question could be more clear... Do you simply want to browse anonymously (for that `tor` is enough) or do you need to hide your IP in other kinds of connections (FTP for example, in which case, I believe you do need `privoxy` and/or `torsocks`.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to modify your repository list. Here is the link for the Ubuntu TOR repository and the steps to modify your list.

https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! There is a new problem: it seems the link https://addons.mozilla.org/extensions/moreinfo.php?application=firefox&id=125 suggested in that webpage I linked does not exist any more. Any suggestion?

Comment: Was that the link for the privoxy addon?

Comment: I was not sure.

Comment: Ok, well without knowing what addon that link was originally for I can't help you too much. I do know that google has lots of Ubuntu/TOR related infomation.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-get install tor` is more than enough, no need for **privoxy**

and under firefox **edit->preferences->advanced->network->settings->manual proxy** configuration do the following:

socks host = **127.0.0.1**
port = **9050**

that's it !!.

and whenever you want to change the ip associated by tor for you just do

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tor restart
```

needs a bit more effort but I'm stuck with this method for a year now and no complaints

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use proxy
and i think you have synaptic program installed on your ubuntu
so easily run it and search "tor"
then install it and search for vidalia and install it too
run vidalia
finished.